# Why laravel duplicates each column with an "index" column?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

why a simple select using Laravel 5.2 is returning a bizarre object with each column repeated with its index.
E.g.:

> $items = DB::select('select colA, colB from foo');
>
> [{
>        "colA": "Max", 
>        "0": "Max", 
>        "colB": "Ana", 
>        "1": "Ana"  }]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because under the hood, Laravel uses [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Default fetching mode for PDO is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which contains both indexes and column names.

You can fine more information in `PDO::fetchAll()` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

If you want to change the fetch mode globally, you can put a `fetch` value to your `/config/database.php` entry:

```php
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
```

Comment: How do I configure that in Laravel? Was not able to find in docs...

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to do that, but are you sure you don't want to use models?

Comment: Thanks! For the update.... About your question.. I am coming from C# and php/laravel are giving me a hard time.. just trying the path with lowest resistance until becoming more proficient. Just making raw selects and throwing the results.

Comment: Things get much easier once you grasp the models, trust me.